# Checkbox que devuelva valor positivo o negativo

Tags: laravel

Tengo un formulario que cuenta con checkbox dinámicos, que después son iterados con un foreach para ser subidos a una base de datos, pero cuando la casilla no está marcada el foreach no reconoce ese checkbox y solo itera los que la casilla si lo están. ¿Como podría hacer que todos los checkbox sean iterados y que los que no están marcados devuelvan 0 o false? Los que si son marcados ya devuelven 1.

De momento estoy utilizando Laravel, pero no se si el problema se podría resolver también con JavaScript, por favor díganme en los comentarios cual les parece la solución más acertada.

**Formulario**

```
 {!! Form::open(['method'=>'GET','url' => '/form_datos']) !!}
                <th>{!!Form::date('fecha',\Carbon\Carbon::now())!!}</th>
            @foreach($tareas as $tarea)
                <td>{!!Form::checkbox('checkbox[]')!!}</td> //este es el checkbox que paso como array al controller
                {!!Form::hidden('tarea_id[]', $tarea->id)!!}
            @endforeach
                <td>{!!Form::submit('Listo')!!}</td>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function datos(Request $request){
    foreach($request->checkbox as $key => $value){
        dato::create([
            'confirm'=>$value, //esta es la linea que recibe el valor que debería ser true o false
            'fecha_id'=>$fecha->id,
            'tarea_id'=>$request['tarea_id'][$key],
            'user_id'=>Auth::id()
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, ya lo pude arreglar. Lo que use fue agregar un input hidden y dependiendo de si estaba chekeada o no la casilla rellenaba el valor de esta hidden, y a la hora de pasar mediante Post los datos en vez de pasar el checkbox pasaba el hidden

```
    <form action="form_datos" method="GET" class="formDatos">
                    <th><input type="date" name="fecha"></th>
                @foreach($tareas as $tarea)
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxButton" value=1 class="checkboxDatos"></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="tarea_id[]" value="{{$tarea->id}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="checkbox[]" class="hiddenCheck" value="{{$tarea->id}}">
                @endforeach
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Listo" class="submitDatos"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <script>
        const $submit = document.querySelector(".submitDatos"),
$checkbox = document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxDatos"),
$form = document.querySelector(".formDatos"),
$hiddenCheck = document.querySelectorAll(".hiddenCheck")


let i = 0;
$form.addEventListener("submit", e=>{
    $checkbox.forEach(el=>{
        console.log(el.checked)
        if(el.checked){
            $hiddenCheck[i].value = 1;
        }else{
            $hiddenCheck[i].value = 0;
        }
        console.log($hiddenCheck[i])
        i++;
    })
})
    </script>
```

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada